# ispell word M-$ goes into screen capture mode on MacOS

Tags: osx, ispell, keyboard

I am on Mac OS X El Capitan.

Here is my version info.

`GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0, NS appkit-1404.47 Version 10.11.6 (Build 15G31)) of 2017-12-03`

**Problem:**
Like most Emacs users on Mac OS I have remapped `Meta` to  <kbd>⌘</kbd>
. So now when I try to do `isepll-word` by doing <kbd>M - $</kbd> it goes into screen capture mode of `Mac OS`. (The way to take a screen capture of a selected portion of your screen is to do <kbd>shift - ⌘ - 4</kbd>), which unfortunately is the same as <kbd>M - $</kbd>.

**Question?**
I when I am in Emacs I want to be able to <kbd>M - $</kbd> and go into the choices for spellings. I know that I can enter this as an extended command as `M-x: ispell-word`. But I'd rather be able to do this with the keyboard shortcut.How can I fix this?.

Comment: It sounds like the key binding is intercepted by the OS before it ever reaches emacs.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The key binding gets intercepted by the OS before it reaches emacs. I have installed emacs via `brew install emacs`

Comment: This looks like an OS issue rather than an emacs issue. You need to turn off the key binding at the OS level.

Comment: You can always type `ESC $`, which shouldn't cause the problem. Maybe there's a way to rebind screen capture in macOS?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I will go ahead and use `ESC $` for nowuntil I figure out a better alternative. I am certainly not going to mess with turning off `apple-key` at the OS level.